# I tried to use this php scipt to remove html tags from a table row (select data and update the row)

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to use this php scipt to remove html tags from a table row. 
(select the data,  strip_tags the string and update the row)

I would be more than thankful for help to find whats wrong.
The "select" is working and i can "echo" or "print" the result and the "strip_tags" is also working.

But, the data is not updated to the table row ? Somthing wrong with the "update" lines?

```
<?php
include_once ("classes/config.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM group_profile WHERE indexer = 4300741";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = @mysql_fetch_array($query);
$group_name = $result['group_description'];
$group_description = strip_tags($group_description, '<p>');


$sql1 = "UPDATE group_profile SET group_name = $group_description WHERE indexer = 4300741";
mysql_query($sql1);
@mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: At a minimum, you should be escaping your data with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  Better yet, learn to do prepared queries with PDO.

Comment: 1. Consider sanitizing queries. 2. var_dump( $group_description ). 3. Is it throwing any errors?

Comment: Just a tiny comment: I read some comments here saying that the data is coming database and no need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` ?? You should know that `mysql_real_escape_string()` is used to escape string in database query and once it's executed and stored on database table, all escape sequences are gone. So if you retrieve the data back and `INSERT` or `UPDATE` you need to do so once again. You still need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Does it make sense? Or maybe this may be helpful [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 1):

did you try this:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE group_profile SET group_name = \'" . mysql_real_escape_string($group_description) . "\' WHERE indexer = 4300741";
```

Comment: This is PHP, not JavaScript.  Also, learn to escape your data.

Comment: Thank you for changing the concatenation operator, but you still need to escape the data you're using in the query.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
$group_name = $result['group_description'];
$group_description = strip_tags($group_description, '<p>');
```

You are using `strip_tags` on an undefined variable.

I am guessing you want something like:

```
$group_description = strip_tags($result['group_description'], '<p>');
```

And the you need to quote the variable in the sql statement:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE group_profile SET group_name = '$group_description' WHERE indexer = 4300741";
```

**Edit:** It seems that escaped data comes back un-escaped from the database, so the correct line would be:

```
$group_description = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($result['group_description'], '<p>'));
```

But prepared statements all the way is the way to go....

Comment: @Brad It comes from the database, it should already have been escaped.

Comment: That's not how this works!!  Who's to say you don't have a stray quote mark or whatever in the group description?  -1  Plus, there is always the possibility of second order SQL injection attack.

Comment: @Brad How is `strip_tags` going to introduce a stray quote mark? Anyway, everybody should just use prepared statements and / or know their data.

Comment: How is `strip_tags()` going to remove quote marks in the first place?  As if a quote mark is all we had to worry about...

Comment: @Brad Look, it comes from the database, so if it was escaped properly when it was put in, escaping it now causes a whole load of extra slashes. You use either prepared statements all the way **or** you escape it when you receive it from the user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9481/discussion-between-brad-and-jeroen)

Answer (score 0):

```
$group_description=mysql_real_escape_string($group_description);
$sql1 = "UPDATE group_profile SET group_name = '$group_description' WHERE indexer = '4300741'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$group_description = strip_tags($result['group_description'], '<p>');
$sql1 = "UPDATE group_profile SET group_name = \"" . mysql_real_escape_string($group_description) . "\" WHERE indexer = 4300741";
```

This way, we strip tags from the right variable, and escape it before inserting into the DB.

It would be even better to use a prepared query.  See a tutorial here:  http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Answer (score 0):

Another point to add to the UPDATE query not working, for debugging only add this to your query line to get a descriptive error message if their is a problem with the query:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Remove the or die after debugging the issue, it could help you resolve the problem, or at least confirm the update is failing because of a syntax error in the query. IE like people said the missing quotes.

Answer (score -1):

`$group_description` is not in quotes, so it would be throwing an error and not updating.  I would try this:

```
$group_description = addslashes(strip_tags($group_description, '<p>'));
$sql1 = "UPDATE group_profile SET group_name = '$group_description' WHERE indexer = 4300741";
```

Comment: `addslashes()` is definitely not appropriate here.  Ever thought about escaping your data?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're missing quotes:

```
$group_description=mysql_real_escape_string($group_description);
$sql1 = "UPDATE group_profile SET group_name = '$group_description' WHERE indexer = 4300741";
```

Comment: It's not untrusted data -- it's already coming from the db, so the lack of escaping can't introduce anything that's not already there.

Comment: ... Who says what's in the database can't mess up a query later?  So what if the first INSERT statement escaped everything properly, and now we have malicious code in there.  A second order attack is very real.  Even if nobody was ever malicious, having quote marks and other stuff in there can mess up the query.  -1